# Compilation error: Type List can't be Generic

Tags: java, generics

I'm new to Java programming, I tried a sample program, the source is found from [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-generics/generic-list.html):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // Compile time error

String string1 = "a string";
list.add(string1);

String string2 = list.get(0);
```

Getting compile time error

```
Error Description:- The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>
```

I'm not sure about this error. Can anyone explain?

Comment: `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: Which Java version do you use?

Comment: Eclipse as the IDE

Comment: Are you using `java.awt.List` or `java.util.List`? The latter is generic and you've probably imported the wrong class by mistake.

Comment: java.awt.List is imported

Comment: @Aishu Well it's the wrong one.

Comment: @kayaman - Now it is working, Thanks

Comment: see in [the docs for java.awt.List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/List.html) and [java.util.List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are importing the wrong `List`. Try the following<sup>*</sup>:

```
java.util.List<String> list = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
```

If it works, just replace the `List` import with the `java.util` one.

Note that the [`java.awt.List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/List.html) is *not* generic, and that's why you're getting the error.

<sup>*</sup> If you're using Java 7+, you can use the [diamond](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>;
```

to

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Sorry I forget to update it in my question. I have declared the same way what u said, but still getting the compile time error

Comment: Then you should follow answer by `Maroun Maroun`

Answer (score 0):

List definition is wrong. It should be like below -

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Putting () let you create the object.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // Compile time error

String string1 = "a string";
list.add(string1);

String string2 = list.get(0);
```

Because it must be:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

NOT

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>;
```

Comment: sorry i will fix it

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you forgot round brackets

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

even if it's generic - you must use usual constructor with\without parameters.